# GTK+ and OpenGL

Tags: c, user-interface, opengl, gtk

What is GTK+ and what does it have to do with OpenGL? Can I create a GUI interface with OpenGL in C? I've researched and people have said to use GTK+ but I simply do not know what it is.

Comment: First result on Google: `GTK+ is a highly usable, feature rich toolkit for creating graphical user interfaces which boasts cross platform compatibility and an easy to use API.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How did you do your "research", one wonders.

Go to the [official GTK+ website](http://www.gtk.org/) and start reading, then go to the corresponding [official OpenGL website](http://www.opengl.org/) and do the same thing there.

GTK+ is an interface toolkit, it uses a drawing backend (GDK+Cairo) to render user interface elements and then manages those elements, handling user input events, redrawing, and on and on.

OpenGL is an API for programming graphics hardware, typically for 3D graphics. It's much tighter in scope (and more low-level) than GTK+, and could (in theory) be used to implement a GTK+ backend.

To illustrate the difference in "level" between the two APIs:

- GTK+ considers a scrollable, editable, multi-font and fully international-language-compliant text view to be a single "thing" that you can work with through its APIs (the mighty [GtkTextView](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/GtkTextView.html) widget).
- OpenGL considers drawing a set of triangles using a single call, that in turn relies on previous calls that have specified coordinates for the triangle's corners, color data, texture coordinates and so on, to be a somewhat high-level call (see [`glDrawElements()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml)).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I couldn't wrap my head around the concepts of both of them at first until now.

Comment: @JakeeL: If you wade through the hundreds of answers I gave at StackOverflow, you'll find one answer where I explain in detail how the different components of GTK+, Cairo, OpenGL, X11 and so on are built on top of each other.